# ServiceStack - Dealing with 'Parameter is never used' warning

Tags: c#, resharper, servicestack, code-analysis

I was running Resharper code analysis on my ServiceStack project and it warns about parameters on certain service actions not being used. Which is true.

The dilemma I am facing is that on routes where there are no parameters needed, such as a simple GET request to return a list of courses:

```cs
[Route("/Courses","GET")]
public class ListCoursesRequest : IReturn<List<CourseResult>> {}
```

Then the action won't use the request object (`ListCoursesRequest`), causing this warning.

```cs
public List<CourseResult> Get(ListCoursesRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

> Warning: Parameter *'request'* is never used.

I could have Resharper ignore the warning by using an ignore comment, but I don't like littering my code this way.

But because ServiceStack routes to the action based on the parameter `ListCoursesRequest` it can't be removed, unless there is a different way to handle the parameterless route scenario. Perhaps an attribute on the action?

I am trying to employ best practises and keep clean code, I know it's cosmetic and I suspect it's just something I'll have to live with, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: `GC.KeepAlive(request);` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Hmm that simple. I knew somebody would have a solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GC.KeepAlive(request);
```

[`GC.KeepAlive` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Importantly:

> The KeepAlive method performs no operation and produces no side effects other than extending the lifetime of the object passed in as a parameter.

---

While *esker*'s solution *(+1)* is useable it's a little cumbersome, as mentioned, it's like using the code comments. I think *MarcGravell*'s suggestion is a simple fix, that is ultimately code-analysis system independent too. *Unfortunately he never posted an answer, just a comment.*

Answer (score 6):

This suggestion is only a little better than adding the ignore comments, but here you go:

If you add [ReSharper code annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html) to your solution, you can mark your DTO and service classes with the `UsedImplicitly` attribute. Specify `ImplicitUseTargetFlags.WithMembers` so you don't have to annotate every offending property and method.

```
[Route("/Courses", "GET"), UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseTargetFlags.WithMembers)]
public class ListCoursesRequest : IReturn<List<CourseResult>> {}

[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseTargetFlags.WithMembers)]
public class CoursesService : Service {
    public List<CourseResult> Get(ListCoursesRequest request) { }
}
```

You can add these ReSharper annotations to your solution by opening ReSharper options and going to the *Code Annotations* tab. There's a button *Copy default implementation to clipboard*. Then you can paste the code into a new file in your solution. Alternatively, I think JetBrains provides a DLL that you can add to your solution, though I prefer pasting in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following extension method, it will be skipped during compilation thanks to Conditional attribute so its really just a "decorator":

```
/// <summary>
/// Does nothing, just avoids "parameter/variable is not used" warnings.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The value.</param>
[Conditional("NEVER")]
public static void DummyUsage<T>(this T value)
{         
    // just dummy code
    if (value is object)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The usage is simple:

```
public List<CourseResult> Get(ListCoursesRequest request)
{
    request.DummyUsage(); // without this line you get a parameter not used warning
}
```